# is that possible to have xml elements referencing each other?

Tags: xml, json, jaxb

let's say i want to build a family tree. so i have:

```
<family name="Smith">
    <member name="Tom">
        <children> ... </children>
    </member>
    <member name="John">
        <father> ... </father>
    </member>
</family>
```

where Tom is John's father.

so my question is:

1. is there a way to mark this kind of relationship easily and the element `father` of John's will be the same object as Tom after unmarshal?
2. how should i annotate the classes?
3. extensively, what is the equivalent way to express the same thing in `json`?

note that in my particular example here, `name` should not serve as key/id, since it's very normal for a family to have multiple people sharing the same name:

```
<family name="Bush">
    <member name="George">
        <children> ... </children>
    </member>
    <member name="George">
        <father> ... </father>
    </member>
</family>
```

i wish to know if there is a way to mark element directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@XmlID` & `@XmlIDREF` for this use case.  The `@XmlID` annotation marks a property as being the key (you will need a property with a unique value, i.e. `name` isn't unique as in your example it looks like in the Bush family there is a father and son named George), and `@XmlIDREF` as a foreign key.  Each object also needs to be referenced through a nesting relationship (in your example this would be accomplished by the `members` property on `Family`.

**For More Information**

I have written more about this use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: what about xml text? some should i represent it?